# Set A + Dynamic DNS record on a domain registrar (bigrock.in) which doesn't support DynDNS without transferring

Tags: web-hosting, ip-address, webserver, dynamic-dns

I have a domain registered with bigrock.in, and I wanna host it on a home webserver. However my home IP address keeps changing and I rely on using clients like ddclient etc. I use them for some domains I own on namecheap.

How do set an A record which is dynamic on bigrock without transferring that domain to namecheap?

Can I just use namecheap's nameservers for my domain on bigrock? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to WSE. Hosting a home server simply requires you using a dynamic DNS service through any number of DNS services such a No-IP.com, Zerigo, Zoneedit etc. It would only require you assigning your nameservers to this service so you can use whichever registrar you like to hold your domain. I would suggest you read this article as a walk through http://linuxhomeserverguide.com/webserver/ddns.php